# Change font size Radar Plot plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly, radar-chart

Does anyone know how can I change the size of the font? I attached a plotly code example.

```
library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly(
type = 'scatterpolar',
r = c(39, 28, 8, 7, 28, 39),
theta = c('A','B','C', 'D', 'E', 'A'),
fill = 'toself'
) %>%
layout(
polar = list(
  radialaxis = list(
    visible = T,
    range = c(0,50)
  )
),
showlegend = F
)
```

I have tried things like: titlefont = list(size = 25), tickfont = list(size = 25)
[image: ra]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
polar = list(radialaxis = list(visible = TRUE, range = c(0, 50)),
             angularaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 20))),
```

in the layout does the job:

[image]